# Should I create a custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do I change UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert default image to custom created?

Is there an easy way or I should create a custom UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard API doesn't support any way to customize the green plus button used for `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`.

Your only option would be use your own button added to a cell. You wouldn't be able to use the standard editing style features of `UITableView`. You would need to set the cell's editing style to `None` and use your own method when the custom button is tapped.

Comment: so how to add that button to cell ? i can only change editingAccessory View

Comment: Add it like you add any subview to a another view. Something like `[cell addSubview:myButton];`. I'd suggest a custom `UITableViewCell` class that does all of the work. Then you can reuse the cell in multiple table views if needed.